# For loop does not add rows to dataframe in R- [R 3.2.2, Win10 Pro, 64-bit]

Tags: r

**Aim**: To loop the process of adding row to a dataframe, using a list, where each element of the list contains 2 objects/elements for 2 columns of the data frame.

Code:

```
  df <- data.frame(hospital = character(), state = character())
  finalList <- list(list("hospital1","state1"),list("hospital2","state2"))

  for(i in seq_len(length(finalList))){
       df[nrow(df)+1, ] <- as.vector(finalList[[i]])
  }
  df
```

**Output**:

```
    Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "a") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "b") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "c") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
4: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "d") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> df
  hospital state
1     <NA>  <NA>
2     <NA>  <NA>
```

Why is the output NA? I have tried using the `print` function in the loop, which does the following:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[1]]
[1] "c"

[[2]]
[1] "d"
```

I am new to R. But, I did rectify the issue by specifying `stringsAsFactors = F`, and have gone through the documentation for `stringsAsFactors`, and googled about factors. What exactly is happening in the code is not very clear, I am aware that `stringsAsFactors` is used during `read.csv` for reading strings either as strings (TRUE value) or as factors (FALSE value), but I am struggling in applying this logic here.

Comment: the columns of `df` are factors with no level, hence when you try to put `a` for example, it's not recognized as an existing level and it results in `NA`. If you define `df` as `df <- data.frame(hospital = character(), state = character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` it works. However, it's very unlikely to be the best solution for you. Growing objects are a very bad idea. How do you get `finalList` ? this could maybe be a data.frame from the start.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is convert a list to a data frame you can do that without a loop. 

`df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(finalList), nrow=length(finalList), byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: @Cath The starting point indeed was a data.frame, this is from the R Programming course at Coursera. The final assignment. I had to `split` the first data.frame, then used lapply, for obtaining the list. The list contains the elements, where every element contains values only from 2 columns. You think I should return a data.frame in every element of one row, and then use rbind?

Comment: @JacobF I indeed did try that, but my list also contains NA values. Which was resulting in shifting of the entire values, as all this expression does is enter the elements from list by unlisting it, and them entering it into a matrix, so when I needed 2 NA's it was only giving 1. Thus, the shift.

Comment: I think you should be more specific on the question you're trying to answer

Comment: @JacobF converting to matrix could cause problems if all variables don't share the same type...

Comment: Maybe something like `t(sapply(finalList, unlist))`

Comment: @Cath I actually posted the part of my logic where I was struggling, as this was an assignment and it would have been unfair on my part to post the entire question. You explained the flaw in my logic very well, and I really appreciate that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

To get the final data.frame, you can try using first `lapply` to put each "prime" element of the list into a data.frame, with desired column names and then merge them by row with `rbind`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(finalList, 
                      function(x) `colnames<-`(data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE), c("state", "hospital"))))
#      state hospital
#1 hospital1   state1
#2 hospital2   state2
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution uses the `plyr` package, specifically the `ldply` function.

```
library(plyr)
finalList <- list(list("hospital1","state1"),list("hospital2","state2"))
# ldply will apply the unlist function to each element to finalList and 
# return a data.frame
hospital_df <- ldply(finalList, unlist)
names(hospital_df) <- c("hospital", "state")
hospital_df
```

If you're unfamiliar with the `plyr` package, you can find quite a good introductions that would go into more detail.